# SQL вывод из трех таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных

У меня есть три таблицы:

1. `orders(id,login,address)`
2. `catalog(id,name,price)`
3. Связующая таблица `id_order_id_goods(id, id_order,id_catalog)`

---

На вход приходит логин пользователя (`login` из таблицы `orders`). Как мне вывести все заказы этого пользователя? То есть, берем `id` из таблицы `orders`, который соответствует данному логину, далее сравниваем этот `id` с `id_order` из таблицы `id_order_id_goods`, берем `id_catalog`, который соответствует `id_order` из данной таблицы и выводим все товары из таблицы `catalog`, где `catalog.id = id_order_id_goods.id_catalog`.

---

Как-то так, но я не понимаю, как это записать.

Comment: Советую прочитать про `[LEFT | INNER] JOIN` и `WHERE`

Comment: @ArchDemon с этим я знаком, я именно сообразить не могу, как это сделать конкретно в этом примере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это так:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM catalog c
    INNER JOIN id_order_id_goods og
        ON og.id_catalog = c.id AND og.id_order=(
            SELECT id FROM orders WHERE login='need_login'
        );
```

Это вернёт вам все записи пользователя в catalog, у которого `login='need_login'`

Если в таблице `orders` несколько записей по 1 `login` то можете сделать так:

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM catalog c
        INNER JOIN id_order_id_goods og
            ON og.id_catalog = c.id AND og.id_order IN (
                SELECT id FROM orders WHERE login='need_login'
            );
```

Comment: А если у пользователя несколько заказов? То есть SELECT id FROM orders WHERE login='need_login' вернет несколько строк

Comment: @volnistii обновил ответ

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает